# ASP.NET MVC -- Remove From Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

My group and I have been struggling to find an answer to this for our website and we've finally taken the step to asking the community for some help!

The goal is the try and link the button of our website to "remove from cart" and set the database back to 0 as well as refresh the page and show the decrementation taking place.

The shopping cart view's javascript does not seem to be working, but I'm not sure if this is ultimately the issue. We've followed many guides such as the MVC music store and ASP.NET documentations.

Index.cshtml:

```
script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");

            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }

                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });

    });


    function handleUpdate() {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        // Update the page elements
        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
        }

        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
    }
</script>

<h3>
    <em>Review</em> your cart:
</h3>
<div id="update-message">
</div>

<div style="height:600px; overflow:auto; padding-top: 50px; margin-left: 200px; width: 1050px; ">
    <table id="cart-summary" border="1" frame="void" rules="rows" style="width:100%;margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <tr class="data-table">
            <th colspan="1">
                Item(s)
            </th>
            <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">
                Price
            </th>
            <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th colspan="1" style="text-align:center;">
                Total
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model.CartItem)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="margin:auto;width:500px;">
                    <div style="float:left;">
                        <a href=@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Books/Details/{0}", item.Book.id))>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Content/img/books/{0}.jpg",item.Book.ISBN))" style="width: 100px; height: 150px;" />

                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-top:37px;">
                        <a href=@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Books/Details/{0}", item.Book.id))>
                            <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Book.Title)</span><br />
                        </a>
                        <span style="text-align:left;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Book.Author)</span><br /><br />
                        <span style="text-align:left">ISBN: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Book.ISBN)</span>
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">@item.Book.PriceNew</p>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center;">@item.Quantity</p>
                    <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.RecordId">Remove from cart</a>
                    <!--data-url='Url.Content("~/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart")'>
                        Remove from cart
                    </a>-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>@Model.CartTotal</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <p style="padding-top:15px;"></p>
                <br />
                <button type="button">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "../Books/Index")
                </button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="cart-total">
                <p style="padding-top: 10px;font-weight:bold;color:rgb(179,0,0);font-size:18px;">Subtotal: @Model.CartTotal</p>
                <button type="button">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Checkout!", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

The next set of code is the C# code.
Cart.cs:

```
public int RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            var cartItem = bookDb.Carts.Single(
                c => (c.CartId == ShoppingCartId)
                && c.RecordId == id);

            int itemCount = 0;

            if (cartItem != null)
            {
                if (cartItem.Quantity > 1)
                {
                    cartItem.Quantity--;
                    itemCount = cartItem.Quantity;
                }
                else
                {
                    bookDb.Carts.Remove(cartItem);
                }
                bookDb.SaveChanges();
            }

            return itemCount;
        }
```

Finally to complete the MVC set of code which relate to each other...We also believe there may be an error here. Again, we just aren't experienced enough to know.

ShoppingCartController.cs:

```
 // GET: ShoppingCart
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Set up our View Model
            var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
            {
                CartItem = cart.GetCartItems(),
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        // GET: Book/Details/5
        // Button that allows you to add to the cart you will be redirected to the Shopping cart index page
        public ActionResult AddToCart(string id)
        {
            var addedBook = bookdb.Books.Single(book => book.ISBN == id);

            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            cart.AddToCart(addedBook);

            bookdb.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // this is attached to the remove to cart button in the shopping cart index page, the index page will then reload
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            // Retrieve the current user's shopping cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the book to display confirmation
            string bookName = bookdb.Carts.Single(book => book.RecordId == id).Book.Title;

            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

            // Display confirmation message
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(bookName) + " has been removed from the shopping cart",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id 
            };
            //return view();
            return Json(results);
        }
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi! Can you create a demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Is the removal of the item happening as expected server-side i.e. when you hit this API endpoint is the item removed from the database?

Comment: It is, I finally figured it out. If you notice the first block of code it shows two scripts. The second is not properly formatted which was the reason the jQuery would be "ignored" so to speak. Then, I had to add the line of code `@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove", "Index", "ShoppingCart", new { LoadingElementId = item.RecordId}, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleUpdate"}, new {@class="RemoveLink", @data_id= @item.RecordId })` in order for the site to recognize that the button/link is going to perform the jQuery functions. I replied in case anyone is having issues! Seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Oh, and just an FYI in case someone runs into this. For Ajax HTML Helpers, you must use an underscore (_) to recognize, in my example, data-id. In other words data-id in HTML is the same as @data_id for HTML Attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Index.cshtml

```
<script>


$(document).on('click', '.del-CartDetail', function () {       

var id = $(this).data("id");        

$("#hdnCartDetailId").val(id);       

 $("#modal-del-cartdetail").modal({            

backdrop: 'static',       
keyboard: false,          
show: true     
  });

});


 $("#btnModalSubmit").click(function () {        
    var buttonText = $("#btnModalSubmit").html();
    $("#btnModalSubmit").attr('disabled', '').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>&nbsp; ' + buttonText);


var id = $("#hdnCartDetailId").val();


$.ajax({
            url: '/CartDetail/DeleteCartDetail',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ Id: id }),
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#modal-del-cartdetail .close').click();
                    //Page redirect after delete record
                    window.location.reload();
                    $('#modal-del-cartdetail').show();
                    INTAPP.Util.Notification(true, "Selected Cart(s) have been successfully deleted.");
                } else {
                    INTAPP.Util.HandleLogout(data.message);
                    INTAPP.Util.Notification(false, "Some error occured while deleting selected Cart.");
                }

                $("#btnModalSubmit").attr('disabled', null).html('Submit');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                INTAPP.Util.Notification(false, error);
                $("#btnModalSubmit").attr('disabled', null).html('Submit');
            }
        });
    });    
</script>


@Html.Partial("ConfirmModal", new ModalViewModel
   {
       Id = "modal-del-cartdetail",
       IsAlertModel = false,
       Title = "Delete Product",
       Message = "Are you sure you want to delete the cart detail?",
       HiddenElementId = "hdnCartDetailId"
   })
```

Comment: I'd recommend to annotate your code. Is this a final solution to the authors issue? The code isn't short, probably explaining it will be helpful.